# How to handle gem conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, squeel

I am using two gems ie squeel and activeadmin and running bundler gives me issue ie:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "polyamorous":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0) ruby

    squeel (>= 0) ruby depends on
      polyamorous (0.6.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby

    delayed_job_active_record (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (3.2.13)
```

How can I handle this? Any idea?

Comment: Does deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and re-running `bundle install` gives you the same error ?

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock of a live project.. Seriously??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's being caused by Metasearch:[image]

Metasearch is no longer being maintained, so we're working on moving to Ransack, its successor. We aren't quite finished, so there hasn't yet been an official release. If you want to go ahead and give it a try:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```